# Excel graphic with 2 x-as variables en 2 y-as variables

Tags: excel, charts

How can I get a chart in Excel with:

- x-as is equal to the combination of JM and location
- y-as are the %-values from Occupied next or on top of empty

So in month 201801 I can see the 2 (or more max 30) locations with both %-values
next to month 201802 and so on.
(Eventualy I can set a trendline on Occupied)

Hopefully my question is clear

The is a short example table:

```
JM  location    Occupied%   Empty%
201801  A           80          20
201801  B           54          46
201802  A           64          36
201802  B           89          11
201803  A           50          50
201803  B           89          11
201804  A           99          1
201804  B           67          33
201805  A           100         0
201805  B           78          22
201806  A           98          2
201806  B           86          14
201807  A           93          7
201807  B           58          42
201808  A           67          33
201808  B           79          21
201809  A           67          33
201809  B           57          43
201810  A           98          2
201810  B           97          3
201811  A           65          35
201811  B           68          32
201812  A           87          13
201812  B           99          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with a pivottable. Select Insert, Pivottable and drag JM to the row field area and Location to the column field area and Occupied to the sigma area. Then insert a line pivot chart.